# Can I play with ETH mining on iMac 27 with AMD M395X (4GB)?

Tags: mac-osx

I have an idle iMax 27 with 2TB Fusion Drive and 4GB AMD 395X GPU. Last time the question was asked was July 2016, so I'll ask again for a current answer.  I am NOT expecting to make any money, but I do want to pretend I can.  My iMac 27 is sitting idle ever since I stopped running BOINC, so this will be just a similar hobby until I get bored.  I do have TG Pro running to watch my CPU and GPU temperatures, all about 100 degrees today sitting idle.

So, not being a programmer and not knowing anything about command lines, I am looking for a current GUI interfaced ETH and BTC miner.  I have the wallet address where I want to deposit any results, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You can mine even just using your CPU if all you want to do is pretend! While the AMD M395X is plenty fast, the OpenCL compiled output (last I checked on MacOS 10.11) was terrible on MacOS; I was using different hardware. I'm trying to find the results of my attempt to figure out how inefficient the result was, but it was probably something like only achieving 1 or 10% of the expected speed. If nothing has changed, you'll get ~1MH/s if you're lucky. If you can boot into another OS that has driver support for the M395X, you may have better luck.

Comment: Okay. Low efficiency is not a deal breaker. I'm just playing, anyway. In fact, I have already made more in one day by day trading a fraction of a bitcoin up and down than I ever hope to make in a year of mining.  I'd need help booting into something other than OSX, but that would only work if that ran in the background while running the normal Apple OS and with normal casual daily use software in the foreground.  In the meantime, this still leaves unanswered the question which software should I try running?  I downloaded MacMiner and thought I was up and running but kept getting an error.

Comment: Yup... I wouldn't give up MacOS for mining, either! I believe I tried ethminer out of the box (compiling it from source did not noticeably improve things). And now to upgrade my computer to High Sierra...

Comment: I did see a reply to an earlier thread with the following, and would appreciate anyone filling in the gaps for me.  I have no idea where to begin to get into command line mode, and whether I need libraries installed that these commands refer to: 

1. Install ethminer:
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install cpp-ethereum
2. Run ethminer:
ethminer -G -F http://somepool.com

Comment: The command line you need is the `Terminal.app` application in `/Applications/Utilities`. The `brew` command comes from homebrew: https://brew.sh . Homebrew is a package manager and *should* install everything you need. (You may need to install some free stuff from Apple first.)

Answer (score 0):

100 degree F is really good, but not reachable, running 100 C continously is to much. Your GPU will die quickly.

You can calculate your expected results i.e. with the whattomine side. http://whattomine.com/

If the 395 results similar to the 380 you get a result of 20 MHs.

In the beginning it's helpful to start with a mining pool like Nanopool.org, you also find on the website infos about mining software, quick start  etc.